# How can I make these vertices/edges elevating/rotating perfectly evenly?

Tags: vertices, edges

I am modeling an SSR MKII rim and I wonder how could I get the selected edges/vertices aligned like the red line:
[image]

I tried rotating by selecting the last vertice highlighted in orange with active element applied but that doesn't rotate the ones next to it in the same way.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Loop Tools" addon.

[image]

LoopTools -> Gstretch

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great thank you :)